# Unable to retrieve full body text for comparison from emails, exported to a .csv file, getting just the 1st line of body text

Tags: powershell, email

I am trying to compare the email body for an email received in Outlook account with certain text.

I have followed following steps:

- Read Outlook
- Fetch the required email from inbox
- Export the emails to a CSV file for comparison
- Compare if the CSV file contains certain text that is to be compared/verified.

However, in my case, the powershell is able compare only the first line of body text from the CSV file, rest lines are not getting compared and the comparison is failing if I include entire body text for comparison in the string.

I have tried following logic with variation of `-contains`, `-like`, `-eq`, `-match`, etc.

If else comparison to compare actual email body with predefined text.

```
If (Select-String -SimpleMatch -List -Pattern $body2 -Path $filelocation1)    
 {   
    Write-Output "Match" 
 }
```

Accessing Outlook mailbox

```
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox) 
$targetfolder = $inbox.Folders | where-object { $_.name -eq "Inbox_Subfolder"}
$email = $targetfolder.items | Where {($_.SenderName -eq "sendername")} |
```

Exporting search results to a csv file

```
Where {$_.Subject -match "subject"} | Out-File -FilePath $filelocation1
$body2="Body Text to be compared, it is around 320 chars"
```

I want to compare all the 320 characters of text in one go & see if the email body in the csv file is matching with the expected email body text.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get-Content` to store the body text

```
Where {$_.Subject -match "subject"} | Out-File -FilePath $filelocation1
$body2 = Get-Content -Path $filelocation1
```

Then condition it with your if statement like so:

```
If ($body2 -match $predefinedtext) {

    Write-Output "Match"
}
```

This will compare against EVERY character with `Get-Content`.